# Jquery get only the selected item in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, onclick

There are bit similar questions like this in which the answers are right. This question is regarding, to get only the selected item not the entire array.

```
<div class="btn-group">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" id="change_regions">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
</ul>
```

If I use something like below I get many attributes which I don't need.

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
   $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
   $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: What do you get here against what is expected?

Comment: I'm getting this `[a.btn.btn-default, a#change_regions.btn.btn-default.dropdown-toggle, prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".btn:first-child"]` This contains many attributes and values. In this I need only the innerHTML for selected dropdown.

Comment: $(this) gives you entire object as opposed to text that you are trying to get. Are you trying to output $(this) alone as is or are you saying $(this).text() gives you many attributes output.

Answer (score 1):

It work alright, updates text of .btn as expected:

`$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
   $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
   $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
});`

https://jsfiddle.net/itsrikin/vseam36j/2/

In your example you dont need to use .val() though, .text() would give you right value.